# Jquery populate an input Textbox instead of the below dropdownlist Code

Tags: jquery

I have a snippit of jquery code that works great(not my code). It works as expected.
How weould I do this if I wanted to populate a text box instead of appending to a  dropdownlist.

JQUERY CODE

```
 $('#ArtistId').append(
  $('<option></option>')
     .val(data.Artist.ArtistId)
     .html(data.Artist.Name)
     .prop('selected', true );
```

TRIED

```
$('#ArtistTexboxId').append($('<input></input>')
                   .val(data.Artist.ArtistId)
                   .html(data.Artist.Name);
```

Comment: You just want to load text into the existing 'ArtistTexboxId'?

Comment: What is ArtistTexboxId  here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('<input/>')
     .attr({
             id: 'ArtistTexboxId',
             name: data.Artist.Name
          })
    .val(data.Artist.ArtistId)
    .appendTo('#ArtistDiv')​;​
```

OR

```
$('#ArtistDiv')
   .append($('<input/>')
                .attr({
                        id: 'ArtistTexboxId',
                         name: data.Artist.Name
                     })
                .val(data.Artist.ArtistId)
          );​
```

**textbox** does not have `innerHtml`

Store that info in the name attribute of the TextBox

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/k6wFv/)**